# Imagen SO con Docker

Tags: docker

Disculpar mi ignorcia en el mundo Docker y virtualización.
He descargado y corrido imagenes de Tomcat, Wordpress, Wildfly, Mysql
Pero no se como correr una imagen de ubuntu o cuaquier otro SO disponible en Docker Hub
Mi intención en montar un SO como si tratra de una maquina virtual en Virtual Box, en la que te bajas la imagen del SO y lo pones en marcha. Pero no se como hacerlo en Docker.

Gracias, un saludo.

Comment: A que te refieres con que has corrido Tomcat, etc. pero no sabes como correr imagenes de ubuntu? Esas imagenes de aplicaciones estan basadas en ubuntu, fedora, etc. Si entidendo lo que quieres es accesar a la linea de comandos del contenedor?

Comment: Disculpa, me refería al GUI del sistema operativo

Answer (score 0):

A diferencia de una máquina virtual la cual es un SO completo. Un contendor ejecuta un sólo proceso raíz y cuando este termina el contenedor termina en estatus "exited". Este proceso raíz puede crear otros procesos hijos.

Por ejemplo las aplicaciones que mencinas contienen la definicion para correr un proceso en segundo plano. Esto para que se mantengan activas durante largo tiempo.

Si quisieras entrar en una linea de comandos tendrías que hacer algo asi:

```
docker run -it ubuntu bash
```

El comando anterior funciona por que le indicas a docker que quieres ejecutar bash como comando. Al momento que salgas de bash el contenedor terminaría pues su unica tarea es ejecutar una aplicación. Debes de tener en cuenta de que no estarías en un SO. Si no en un entorno que simula un SO con su propio sistema de archivos, etc.

Ademas mencionas que quieres configurar el contenedor. El contenedor por lo regular ya viene con su imagen configurada para que la ejecutes. No se trabaja como una VM en la cual las modificaciones que hagas se guardan entre reinicios.

Támbien tienes que conocer la diferencia entre [ENTRYPOINT y CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/). Asi como el formato Dockerfile para crear tu imagen y no tener que configurar el contenedor una vez que este corriendo.